# How to increase file size in wordpress version 3.6

Tags: wordpress

im trying to increase the file media size in wordpress but having no look i have done the pho.ini file and increased it that way but no look, perhaps wordpress have locked it down so you cant change the maximum file size, ive had a look around blogs and everyone is using the php.ini file but none of the blogs are very recent so i cant get a solution because they are all for the old versions of wordpress. and my hosting provider hasn't capped my upload limits, my current php.ini file is this:

```
   memory_limit = 52M
   upload_max_filesize = 100M
   upload_max_filesize = 100M
   post_max_size = 100M
```

i have changed this many a time to increase my file upload limit to 6GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it for your domain from your end..YOu can either do it from wp-config.php or .htaccess file of your domain. Here is the code for that:

For `wp-config.php:`

```
define(’WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ‘64M’);
```

For `.htaccess:`

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The location of the file php.ini depends on the installation of PHP.

The safest way to know it, is through the following script:

phpinfo();

**Modify the php.ini file**

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M

post_max_size = 64M
```

**Created a .htaccesss file in the wordpress root dir with the following:**

```
 php_value upload_max_filesize 64M

 php_value post_max_size 64M

 php_value max_execution_time 300

 php_value max_input_time 300
```

**For wp-config.php file in the wordpress root dir:**

```
define(’WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ‘64M’);
```